# Migrations & Models in Attendance Tracking Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I want to put together an application (ruby on rails + mysql) that can track "user" attendance, however, I'm struggling with how to organize the data into tables. I'd appreciate suggestions on possible table/migration structures. Following is what I've come up with thus far:

*attendance* table

```
date DATE
user_id INT
status INT
```

Essentially, I want to (much like an attendance register) mark a "user" present for a full-day/half-day or absent. And I'd like to be able to review the attendance record for a user, for a variable period (i.e. past 30 days, 15 days, 3 days, etc.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would use three models: Day, User, and Record.

```
class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :records
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :records
end

class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :day
end
```

`Day` would obviously have a date field, and `Record` would have a status field to hold whether the user was present, absent, etc, on that day.

Structuring it like this allows you to query by user, date (including ranges), status, or any combination of the three.

For example, counting a user's absences:

```
Record.where(:user_id => @user.id, :status => 'absent').count
```

Comment: Wouldn't I be able to query by user, date (including ranges), status, etc. if there were only two models, `Record` and `User`, as well?

Comment: You could, but it doesn't allow you to add any additional attributes to each day. Making `Day` independent of `Record` would let you add things like a `Notes` field or `Holiday` tag, for example. It's just more flexible and makes adding things in the future much easier.